# Unable to execute Selenium asynchronous script

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Why am I getting an exception with selenium 2.25.0 when trying to execute asynchronous script.

```
//navigate to my test page.

String script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];"  +
                "getResult(callback)";

Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(script, "");

System.out.println(result);
```

The test page contains the following script:

```
var result = true;
function getResult(callback){
    window.setTimeout(function(){callback(true);}, 3000);
}
```

This throws an exception:

```
FAILED: testSeleniumAsync
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Script execution failed. Script: var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];getResult(callback);
 Timed out waiting for asyncrhonous script result after 2 ms (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-27-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: 6347b507cf22b6c2d3312937a82a0a02
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
```

If I remove the setTimeout from my script and I call callback it works. But this is not what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its very strange that the API is timing out in 2 ms.

I am guessing that the script time out is somehow incorrectly configured (<= 0sec). Since your window timeout occurs after 3 secs, try setting the script time out to some value greater than 3 secs, before you make the call.

Like so:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

That might work.

Comment: Let me add something I think to be a common pitfall, ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(script, ""); // will return immediately.

Comment: @redsonic +1 any day.
But in this case the OP is invoking the callback.

Comment: I have the same issue in protractor, how can i configure it ?
i did browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000); but i have the same error !

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu, I've the same issue in perl selenium. I tried with adding $driver->set_async_script_timeout(1000); before calling $driver->execute_async_script method but it still give me error. Please help!

Comment: Docs for `executeAsyncScript()` says "The default timeout for a script to be executed is 0ms. In most cases, including the examples below, one must set the script timeout WebDriver.Timeouts.setScriptTimeout(java.time.Duration) beforehand to a value sufficiently large enough."